# How to use `boost::thread_specific_ptr` with `for_each`

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

In the code below, `Bar` is supposed to model a thread-unsafe object that is moderately expensive to create. `Foo` contains a `Bar` and is multi-threaded, so it uses a `thread_specific_ptr<Bar>` to make a per-thread `Bar` that can be re-used across multiple calls to `loop` for the same `Foo` (therefore amortizing the cost of creating a `Bar` for each thread). `Foo` always creates a `Bar` with the same `num`, so the sanity check is *supposed* to always pass, yet it fails.

The reason for this is (I think) explained in the [requirement for the `thread_specific_ptr` destructor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html#thread.thread_local_storage.thread_specific_ptr.destructor):

> All the thread specific instances associated to this thread_specific_ptr (except maybe the one associated to this thread) must be null.

So the problem is caused by a combination of three things:

1. `Bar` objects created in worker threads are not cleaned up when `Foo`s `thread_specific_ptr` is cleaned up, and are therefore persisted across iterations of the loop in `main` (essentially, a memory leak)
2. The C++ runtime is re-using threads in `for_each` between iterations of the loop in `main`
3. The C++ runtime is re-allocating each `Foo` in the `main` loop to the same memory address

The way that `thread_specific_ptr`s are indexed (by the `thread_specific_ptr`'s memory address and the thread ID) results in old `Bar`s being accidentally reused. I understand the problem; what I don't understand is what to do about it. Note the remark from the docs:

> The requirement is due to the fact that in order to delete all these instances, the implementation should be forced to maintain a list of all the threads having an associated specific ptr, which is against the goal of thread specific data.

I'd like to avoid this complexity as well.

How can I use `for_each` for simple thread management, but also avoid the memory leak? Solution requirements:

- It should only create one `Bar` per thread per `Foo` (i.e., don't create a new Bar inside the `for_each`)
- Assume `Bar` is not thread-safe.
- If possible, use `for_each` to make the parallel loop as simple as possible
- The loop should actually run in parallel (i.e., no mutex around a single `Bar`)
- `Bar` objects created by `loop` should be available for use until the `Foo` object that created them is destructed, at which point all `Bar` objects should also be destructed.

The following code compiles and should exit with return code 1 with high probability on a machine with sufficient cores.

```
#include <boost/thread/tss.hpp>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Bar {
    public:
    // models a thread-unsafe object
    explicit Bar(int i) : num(i) { }
    int num;
};

class Foo {
    public:
    explicit Foo(int i) : num(i) { }

    void loop() {
        vector<int> idxs(32);
        iota(begin(idxs), end(idxs), 0);
        for_each(__pstl::execution::par, begin(idxs), end(idxs), [&](int) {
            if (ptr.get() == nullptr) {
                // no `Bar` exists for this thread yet, so create one
                Bar *tmp = new Bar(num);
                ptr.reset(tmp);
            }
            // Get the thread-local Bar
            Bar &b = *ptr;

            // Sanity check: we ALWAYS create a `Bar` with the same num as `Foo`;
            // see the `if` block above.
            // Therefore, this condition shouldn't ever be true (but it is!)
            if (b.num != num) {
               cout << "NOT THREAD SAFE: Foo index is " << num << ", but Bar index is " << b.num << endl;
               exit(1);
            }
        });
    }
    boost::thread_specific_ptr<Bar> ptr;
    int num;
};

int main() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Foo f(i);
        f.loop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the lifetime of the Bars?  They *must* have a defined lifetime, and you *must* clean up every thread specific Bar in every thread you create it.

Comment: Ideally, all of the `Bar`s created by a single `Foo` should be cleaned up when the `Foo` is cleaned up (whether or not the thread associated with the `Bar` is cleaned up). I initially thought that the destructor for the `thread_specific_ptr` would do that, but the documentation explicitly states otherwise.

Comment: Also for the love of god don't `using namespace std;
using namespace boost;` - do you want the only person who can understand your code be someone with the entire std, all clang extensions, and all of boost memorized so they can work out which for each you called?  I suspect the only boost is thread specific, but it will literally require undoing those using namespaces to make sure.

Comment: Can't you use the native C++11 `thread_local` instead?

Comment: @JDługosz If you think it will work, write an answer...

Comment: Since @JDługosz never responded: it looks like `thread_local` variables cannot be instance variables, and therefore this does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html#thread.thread_local_storage.thread_specific_ptr.destructor)

```
~thread_specific_ptr();

Requires:
  All the thread specific instances associated to this thread_specific_ptr 
  (except maybe the one associated to this thread) must be null.
```

This means you are not allowed to destroy `Foo` until all of its `Bar` have been destroyed. This is a problem because `execution_policy::par` does not have to operate on a fresh thread pool, nor does it have to terminate the threads once the `for_each()` is done.

This gives us enough to answer the question as asked: You can only use `thread_specific_ptr` alongside `execution::par` to share data between various iterations on the same thread if:

- The `thread_specific_ptr` is never destroyed. This is required because there is no way to know whether a given iteration of the `for_each` will be the last one for its assigned thread, and that thread might *never* get scheduled again.
- You are comfortable leaking one instance of the pointed object per thread until the end of the program.

**What's going on in your code**

We are already in Undefined Behavior land, but the behavior you are seeing can still be explained a bit further. Considering that:

> Boost.Thread uses the address of the thread_specific_ptr instance as key of the thread specific pointers. This avoids to create/destroy a key which will need a lock to protect from race conditions. This has a little performance liability, as the access must be done using an associative container.

... and that all 100 instances of `Foo` will most likely be at the same place in memory, you end up seeing instances of `Bar` from the previous `Foo` when the worker threads are recycled, leading to your (innacurate, see below) check to hit.

**Solution: What I think you should do**

I would suggest you just drop `thread_specific_ptr` altogether and manually manage the pool of per-thread/per-`Foo` `Bar` instances with an associative container, this makes managing the lifetime of the `Bar` objects a lot more straightforward:

```cpp
class per_thread_bar_pool {
  std::map<std::thread::id, Bar> bars_;
  // alternatively: 
  // std::map<std::thread::id, std::unique_ptr<Bar>> bars_;
  std::mutex mtx_;

public:
  Bar& get(int num) {
    auto tid = std::this_thread::get_id();

    std::unique_lock l{mtx_};
    auto found = bars_.find(tid);
    if(found == bars_.end()) {
        l.unlock(); // Let other threads access the map while `Bar` is being built.
        Bar new_bar(num);
        // auto new_bar = std::make_unique<Bar>(num); 
        l.lock();

        assert(bars_.find(tid) == bars_.end());
        found = bars_.emplace(tid, std::move(new_bar)).first;
    }
    return found->second;
    // return *found->second;
  }
};


void loop() {
    per_thread_bar_pool bars;
    vector<int> idxs(32);
    iota(begin(idxs), end(idxs), 0);

    for_each(__pstl::execution::par, begin(idxs), end(idxs), [&](int) {
        Bar& current_bar = bars.get(num);
        // ...
   }
}
```

`thread_specific_ptr` already uses `std::map<>` under the hood (it maintains one per thread). So introducing one here is not that big of a deal.

We do introduce a mutex, but it only comes into play for a simple lookup/insertion into a map, and since constructing `Bar` is supposed to be so expensive, it will most likely have very little impact. It also has the benefit that multiple instances of `Foo` do not interact with each other anymore, so you avoid surprising bugs that could occur if you ever end up calling `foo::loop()` from multiple threads.

**N.B.**: `if (b.num != num) {` is not a valid test since all instances of `Bar` from a given `Foo` share the same `num`. That should only cause false-negatives though.

**Solution: Making your code work (almost)**

All this being said, if you are absolutely gung-ho about using `thread_specific_pointer` and `execution::par` at the same time you'll have to do the following:

```
void loop() {
        static boost::thread_specific_ptr<Bar> ptr; // lives till the end of the program

        vector<int> idxs(32);
        iota(begin(idxs), end(idxs), 0);
        for_each(__pstl::execution::par, begin(idxs), end(idxs), [&](int) {
            if (ptr.get() == nullptr || ptr->num != num) {
                // no `Bar` exists for this thread yet, or it's from a previous run
                Bar *tmp = new Bar(num);
                ptr.reset(tmp);
            }
            // Get the thread-local Bar
            Bar &b = *ptr;

        });
```

However, this **will** leak up to 1 `Bar` per thread, as cleanup only ever happens when we try to reuse a `Bar` from a previous run. There are no ways around this.